# Persistent "Not found" error when calling methods

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am using Flask in Python and I am trying to elaborate post requests on the server I am hosting (atm on localhost because I am still trying to make it work).

```
results =  requests.post(url, input_data)

#send input values and prediction result to index.html for display
return render_template("index.html", age = age, job = job, marital = marital, education = education, default = default, balance = balance, housing = housing, loan = loan,  results=results.content.decode('UTF-8'))
```

I keep getting the following error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>404 Not Found</title> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

The code I am using is the following:
I have two files
main.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from application import routes

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host = 'localhost', port = 5000, debug = True)
```

And routes.py

```
from application import app
from flask import render_template, request, json, jsonify
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
import requests
import numpy
import pandas as pd

#decorator to access the app
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
  return render_template("index.html")

#decorator to access the service
@app.route("/bankclassify", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def bankclassify():

  #extract form inputs
  age = request.form.get("age")
  job = request.form.get("job")
  marital = request.form.get("marital")
  education = request.form.get("education")
  default = request.form.get("default")
  balance = request.form.get("balance")
  housing = request.form.get("housing")
  loan = request.form.get("loan")

 #convert data to json
  input_data = json.dumps({"age": age, "job": job, "marital": marital, "education": education, "default": default, "balance": balance, "housing": housing, "loan": loan})

  #url for bank marketing model
  url = "http://localhost:5000/api"
  #url = "https://bank-model-app.herokuapp.com/api"

  #post data to url
  results =  requests.post(url, input_data)

  #send input values and prediction result to index.html for display
  return render_template("index.html", age = age, job = job, marital = marital, education = education, default = default, balance = balance, housing = housing, loan = loan,  results=results.content.decode('UTF-8'))
```

I tried changing the port but it did not solve it.
Thank you so much

Comment: Well, is there an actual `index.html` file with the template for it to render?

Comment: Yes I have the file with the template for it to render

Comment: You're posting to `http://localhost:5000/api` but there's no `/api` route in that file?